# Oracle SQL Distinct with 3 Join Tables

Tags: sql, oracle, join, distinct

I would like to join my 3 tables.

The current I set only 2 tables. Now got confused how to join it.

Table: `WA_GA_TBL_ARTICLES` with attribute: `ARTICLEID` and `INVENTORYID_FK`.

Here is the query:

```
SELECT
DISTINCT
S.FORM_NO,
S.ARTICLEID_FK,
S.BOX_SERIAL_NO,
S.ACTUAL_WEIGHT,
TO_CHAR(S.DATEADDED, 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') AS DATEADDEDS,
S.ADDEDBY,
B.BOX_SERIAL_NO,
B.ARTICLEID_FK,
B.DATE_CODE,
B.SO_NO
FROM WA_LA_TBL_ARTICLES_SCAN S JOIN
WA_LA_TBL_ARTICLES_BOX_SN B
ON S.BOX_SERIAL_NO = B.BOX_SERIAL_NO AND
TO_CHAR(S.DATEADDED, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI') BETWEEN '2018-08-01 08:00' AND '2018-08-02 07:59'
ORDER BY S.ARTICLEID_FK, B.BOX_SERIAL_NO ASC
```

My question, how to join `WA_GA_TBL_ARTICLES` above query with parameter `ARTICLEID = B.ARTICLEID_FK`

Any idea?

Comment: can'T understand your Problem. why you can't add a second join to your select?

Comment: The above query with 2 tables working good. And now I want to add 1 table `WA_LA_TBL_ARTICLES` to join with that 2 tables. How to do that?

Comment: You have the query as an example of writing joins. You have the join criterion. Where does the confusion come from?

Comment: Left justified SQL is so hard to read...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT
      S.FORM_NO,
      S.ARTICLEID_FK,
      S.BOX_SERIAL_NO,
      S.ACTUAL_WEIGHT,
      TO_CHAR(S.DATEADDED, 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') AS DATEADDEDS,
      S.ADDEDBY,
      B.BOX_SERIAL_NO,
      B.ARTICLEID_FK,
      B.DATE_CODE,
      B.SO_NO
FROM WA_LA_TBL_ARTICLES_SCAN S 
JOIN WA_LA_TBL_ARTICLES_BOX_SN B
    ON S.BOX_SERIAL_NO = B.BOX_SERIAL_NO 
   AND TO_CHAR(S.DATEADDED, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI') BETWEEN '2018-08-01 08:00' AND '2018-08-02 07:59'
join WA_GA_TBL_ARTICLES w  on  w.ARTICLEID = B.ARTICLEID_FK
ORDER BY S.ARTICLEID_FK, B.BOX_SERIAL_NO ASC
```

Answer (score 1):

If i understand rigth you could add the join

```
  SELECT
  DISTINCT
  S.FORM_NO,
  S.ARTICLEID_FK,
  S.BOX_SERIAL_NO,
  S.ACTUAL_WEIGHT,
  TO_CHAR(S.DATEADDED, 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') AS DATEADDEDS,
  S.ADDEDBY,
  B.BOX_SERIAL_NO,
  B.ARTICLEID_FK,
  B.DATE_CODE,
  B.SO_NO
  FROM WA_LA_TBL_ARTICLES_SCAN S 
  JOIN WA_LA_TBL_ARTICLES_BOX_SN B ON S.BOX_SERIAL_NO = B.BOX_SERIAL_NO AND
  TO_CHAR(S.DATEADDED, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI') BETWEEN '2018-08-01 08:00' AND '2018-08-02 07:59'

  JOIN  WA_GA_TBL_ARTICLES C ON C.ARTICLEID = B.ARTICLEID_FK 

  ORDER BY S.ARTICLEID_FK, B.BOX_SERIAL_NO ASC
```

and add  the WA_GA_TBL_ARTICLES C  you need  in select